# Help Starting Minecraft Server Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: command-line, server, minecraft, sh

My .sh file to launch the server is not working. I have the file named 'craftbukkit.sh'  with this pasted in it (from the bukkit set up wiki)

```
#!/bin/sh
BINDIR=$(dirname "$(readlink -fn "$0")")
cd "$BINDIR"
java -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true
```

and i downloaded the latest version of bukkit and named it 'craftbukkit.jar' and put it in the same directory as the .sh file. i right clicked and allowed executing file as program. under file manager, execute text files is set to ask each time. i click the .sh file and tell it to open in the terminal. the terminal opens and closes real quick each time. i also have java RE 7 downloaded from the software ceneter.

any ideas? i have hosted minecraft servers on older versions before and never had difficulties to the point of having to post online. thanks.

Comment: Try running the script from within an already open terminal to see why it closes immediately. Add any errors to your question as an [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/557511/edit)

Comment: To my knowledge, you can just remove the 2nd and 3rd lines and it should work. Maybe you don't have a JRE installed?

Answer (score 0):

The second and third lines of your script are unnecessary. Your script should look like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
java -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true
```

Here's a breakdown of what each line of the script does:

```
#!/bin/sh
```

This line causes your script to be invoked by `/bin/sh`, which is (in the case) the `bash` shell

```
java -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit.jar -o true
```

This line actually starts the server (`craftbukkit.jar` must be in the same directory.

`-Xmx1024M` sets the maximum amount of memory available to the process to **1GB**, or **1024 MB**. If you get an `OutOfMemoryError`, you'll need to increase this.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is because you installed Bukkit and not Craftbukkit. Here you have a link to download craftbukkit:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/giz9me8xcgkb1qa/craftbukkit.jar?dl=0

CraftBukkit does not work to download on bukkit.org. It just shows an error: http://dl.bukkit.org/latest-rb/craftbukkit.jar
It worked for me.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)